# Open source software for 3 D vector editing on top of stereo images

Tags: software-recommendations, free-software, photogrammetry

I am looking for an open source software that could be used to digitize 3D vector objects from a stereo pair of remotely sensed images. Photogrammetry softwares are too expensive for my use (giving an introduction course to 60 students, which means only a dozen of hours every year).

I know a few software that can process stereo images to generate ortho-images and DSM (e.g. MICMAC, OTB...). However, I would like to be able to display an epipolar pair in 3D (e.g. with anaglyph or other 3D devices) and draw some 3D objects directly in 3D. Does it exists (or are you aware of future plug ins to existing OS photogrammetry softwares)?

Comment: OpenMVG is worth a look http://imagine.enpc.fr/~moulonp/openMVG/

Comment: thanks for the link, but I do not see any features in the description that could be used to manually draw a line directly on a true 3D view.

Answer (score 1):

On Micmac you can draw 3D polygon, point and line with SaisieMasq_QT. This tool allow to draw 3D vector on front of the orthoimage, point cloud or the mesh. It will create an XML file with 3D coordinates.

EDIT : just edit the name of the function

After some research, Poivilliers F is a software from IGN France, to draw 3D on stereoscopic images. It's open source CeCILL licence. It could be download from the ENSG e-learning plateform [here](https://www.partage-fichiers.com/upload/ppmiaekc), with other photogrammetric software. the documentation is in French.

Comment: see the doc [here](http://logiciels.ign.fr/IMG/pdf/docmicmac-2.pdf)

Comment: thank you, but can you do this on a stereo image (not on ortho). It is interestig to be able to draw a line that is converted in 3D automatically, but I would prefer to work in stereo.

Comment: sorry I don't know with micmac. Maybe you should ask on the [micmac forum](http://forum-micmac.forumprod.com/). I think you should make the process to realize a point cloud file and the DEM. After that, Grass software have the r.profile function to make an elevation profil (not sure is what you need).

Comment: After some research, Poivilliers F is a software from IGN France, to draw 3D on stereoscopic images. It's open source CeCILL licence. It could be download from the ENSG e-learning plateform : [here](http://partage.informatique-libre.org/dl/c0763d), with other photogrametric softwares.  the documentation is in French.

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa could you update the link? I'm trying to find the software but cant

Comment: I don't maintain the url but i request the new url one to IGN team. you can find it  [there](https://www.partage-fichiers.com/upload/ppmiaekc)  I edited the answer with this tools